# Can I assume that the Delphi NOW function will be thread safe?

Tags: delphi, time, thread-safety

If I call NOW from within multiple threads can I assume that this is ok or do I need to implement locking for this? I know that date time formatting is not safe but what about date time reading? 
In addition, what about QueryPerformanceCounter? I've looked but can't find any definitive documentation on thread safety for these low level functions.

Comment: Now is thread safe. Date formatting also if you do it right. QueryPerformanceCounter also thread safe. Windows API is thread safe.

Comment: Documentation should warn you when Api function is NOT threadsafe. By default functions are threadsafe nowadays.

Comment: Date formatting done right means using the function versions that take a `TFormatSettings` parameter.

Comment: Or calling the functions that don't receive parameters and never changing the global FormatSettings variable (if that's what it's called)

Comment: That's not thread safe, since other functions may still change the global settings while this function is using them.

Comment: @Golez That's precisely what I said. So long as you never change that shared data, it's thread safe.

Comment: Thanks to David, Marjan and Serg for the conclusive message "By default functions are threadsafe nowdays"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have access to `SysUtils.pas`? I have my old Delphi4 sources and there in `Source\Rtl\Sys\SysUtils.pas` is implementation of `Now()`. It seems that it uses Win API `GetLocalTime()` and its own `EncodeDate()` and `EncodeTime()` functions. They all are thread safe so `Now()` is also thread safe.

Comment: calling threadsafe functions in a function body - a();  b(); Result := c(); can still be thread-unsafe code

Comment: Yes, but `Now()` uses only its own variables and there should be no side effects.

Comment: @Michal - Interesting, yes. I have my own 'Now' which calls QueryPerformanceCounter to get a TDateTime with 100ns resolution, so yes, the safe 'its thread safe' conclusion applies.

Comment: `TDateTime` only has millisecond precision, so why use QPC (which is known to NOT be safe in a multi-CPU environment, BTW) to retreive nanosecond-resolution date/time values?

Comment: @RemyLebeau QPC gives us hardware pulses and duration timng to microsecond duration and if you do some testing TDateTime which is a double BTW can hold this resolution. It's the Now and GetTickCount functions that have 1ms resolution.

Comment: But nothing in the RTL actually utilizes microseconds, even if `TDateTime` can physically hold them.

Comment: QPC/QPF API is known to provide unreliable results for some systems, due to chipset bugs. OSes are trying to utilize hardware timers and provide reliable timings but that is not always possible.

Comment: @Remy No, that's true but I have my own routines for that DelayMicroseconds(AValue : integer) etc. Out of interest, checking my previous investigations I see that TDateTime (double) has a resolution of approx 7.3E-12, i.e about 8ps using typical present-day dates. 'Adjacent' values today are 4.12454337469792E+004 and  4.12454337469792E+004 which are 7.27595761418343E-012 apart.